# Firebase Analytics console doesn't show up because of X-Frame-Options error

Tags: xcode, firebase, firebase-analytics

I started to use Firebase Analytics on my developing app, but the analytics console doesn't appear. I can't see even the navigation bar.

Here's a [screenshot of my analytics console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wah25.png).

I installed `Firebase/Core` pods, set `-FIRAnalyticsDebugEnabled`, and debug console on Xcode says analytics data uploaded successfully.

My first event data sent about 20 hours ago. I'm planning to wait until 24 hours will pass, but is there any possible setting required?

---edit---
I found an error message in my browser's developers console. Here's a [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Wa1S.png).
It seems some kind of `X-Frame-Options` problem.
I tried Safari and Chrome, but the results are same.

Comment: Clear browser cache?  Force reload the page?  Even if your app hasn't generated any analytics events, you should see something there.

Comment: In the developers console of my browser, I found the `X-FRAME-OPTIONS` error. Added the screenshot to my question.  
I tried Safari and Chrome, but the results are same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found it's a problem of Google account's permission. I used my company's Google account and already got the permission to access Firebase, but permission for **Google Analytics** seems necessary too!
After getting another permission from the admin in my company, Firebase Analytics console appeared in a right way.